# Laravel Migrations insert into table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

In Laravel 5.3 within my `up()` function how can I insert data into another table?

I can only see things in the guide for updating columns etc

Comment: The point of Migration is to modify and share the application's database **schema**, not to insert data. If you want to insert dummy/initial data, take a look at [seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/seeding).

Comment: @haitran thanks with the seeder would I run    DB::table('db')->insert([ for each lot of data I want to insert into the db - looking at doing    DB::table('db')->insert([ 4 or 5 times with diff info

Comment: From what I understand, you need to insert more than one row at a time, if I'm correct, then you just need to put your data in an array as: `DB::table('users')->insert([['array data 1'], ['array data 2'], ['array data 3']]);`.

Comment: @haitran is correct! you can even use `Model::unguard()` before you start if you would rather use model functions to create your models.  This will remove the restriction of the `$fillable` variable

Comment: @Jeff its unguarded by default in `5.3` when seeding.

Here is link to this change https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it as what you do in normal Laravel code as long as that table has been created already. For example:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('this_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    \DB::table('that_table')->insert([]);
}
```

As others suggest, you should consider if it's better to move such logic into database seeders. However, I find sometimes it's better to have such logic just live inside migration files when your table have constant initial data.

FYI, [Here](https://github.com/summerblue/phphub/blob/master/app/database/migrations/2014_08_10_091306_create_nodes_table.php) is an open source Laravel project does this.

===========Edit 5 years later=============

I suggest anyone want to do this consider database seeders as the original answer suggested. Now Laravel have a [`schema:dump`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#squashing-migrations) command that can be used for squashing your migrations. This might be useful if you have a project with many migrations. For me, I have a project with 408 migrations and it's not easy to use the `schema:dump` now as data filling methods in migrations will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

> You can insert to the table as shown below after the table is created.

```
    DB::table('tablename')->insert([
        ['columnname1' => 1, 'columnname2' => 'Girl'],
        ['columnname1' => 2, 'columnname2' => 'Boy']
    ]);
```